# django-tables2: Cannot sort a custom column using order_by

Tags: django, django-tables2

I created a new column (issue_number) which represents just the "pk" of the table, but in the model retrieves an object:

```
@property
def issue_number(self):
    return self
```

The problems comes when I want to order the table with that column. I get a random order, maybe this is because I'm order not via the integer but via the object.

If I mouse over the header column, I get = "?sort=issue_number" but I would like to have "?sort=id"

```
class IssueNumberColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        obj = value
        if obj.status.upper() in ['RESOLVED', 'INVALID']:
            return mark_safe('<a href="%s"><s>#%s</s></a>' % (reverse('issues.views.view', args=(obj.pk,)), obj.pk))
        else:
            return mark_safe('<a href="%s">#%s</a>' % (reverse('issues.views.view', args=(obj.pk,)), obj.pk))

class IssueTable(tables.Table):
    issue_number = IssueNumberColumn(verbose_name="ID", order_by='pk')
    #id = tables.Column(accessor='pk')

    def render_id(self, value):
        return mark_safe('<a href="%s">#%s</a>' % (reverse('issues.views.view', args=(value,)), value))

    def render_title(self, value, record):
        return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (reverse('issues.views.view', args=(record.id,)), value))

    def render_created(self, value):
        #without doing this, it shows American date formatting.
        return value

    class Meta(object):
        model = Issue
        fields = ('issue_number', 'title', 'product', 'type', 'priority', 'status', 'created')
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered'}
        empty_text = _('No records found')
```

I have done many attempts but nothing helps:

```
    issue_number = IssueNumberColumn(verbose_name="ID", order_by='pk')
    issue_number = IssueNumberColumn(verbose_name="ID", order_by='id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tuple for `order_by` instead of a string:

```
order_by=('pk',)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Using `order_by = ('id',)` or `order_by = 'id'` doesn't work if 'id' is not declared into fields.

So I recommend you to add the column in this way:

```
id = tables.Column(visible=False)
```

and then add the field 'id' into 'fields'. Example:

```
  fields = ('id', 'title', 'description')
```

I hope it will be useful to somebody.